# Relationship between exterior and directional derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

For a smooth $k$-form $\omega$ I know the formula
$$
\begin{split}
\mathrm{d} \omega (X_0,\dots,X_k)
 &= \sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^i X_i(\omega(X_0,\dots,\hat{X_i},\dots,X_k)) \\
 &+ \sum_{i<j} (-1)^{i+j} \omega([X_i,X_j],X_0,\dots,\hat{X_i},\dots,\hat{X_j},\dots,X_k),
\end{split}$$
which relates the directional derivatives of the functions $p \mapsto \omega(X_0,\dots,\hat{X_i},\dots,X_k)\big{\rvert}_p$ to $\mathrm{d}$. I guess it should be true that if $p\mapsto \mathrm{d} \omega (X_0,\dots,X_k)\big{\rvert}_p$ is a bounded function, then $p \mapsto X_i(\omega(X_0,\dots,\hat{X_i},\dots,X_k))\big{\rvert}_p$ is bounded as well. However, I can't manage to proof this. I checked these two functions in local coordinates and tried to connect them, but it seems that I end up at the above formula. Is this even true and if yes, how to prove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason why this should be true. If you take $\omega$ to be the exterior derivative of some $(k-1)$-form, then $d\omega=0$ but this certainly does not imply that $X_i(\omega(X_0,\dots,\widehat{X_i},\dots,X_k))$ is bounded for arbitrary vector fields $X_j$.

Comment: My reason was that we have $\mathrm{d}f_p(X) = X(f)$ for a function on euclidean space. Could you explain why this directional derivative is certainly not bounded?

Comment: If you think about $df$ rather than $f$, then you simply have that $0=X(Y(f))-Y(X(f))-[X,Y](f)$ for arbitrary vector fields $X$ and $Y$. But this does not imply that $X\cdot df(Y)=X(Y(f))$ is bounded. For an explicit example take $f$ on $\mathbb R^2$, $f(x,y)=xy^2$. Then $df=y^2dx+2xydy$ so putting $Y=\partial_y$ you get $df(Y)=xy$ and differentiating this in direction $X=\partial_x$ you get $y$ which is unbounded. But still $d(df)=0$ so $d(df)(X,Y)=0$, so this is bounded. For forms of higher degree, $d$ only "sees" a small part of the directional derivatives.